# join relationships of joined relationship sqlalchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have these tables that I need to join manually on certain occasions:

```
class Event(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    node_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('node.id'), nullable=False)
    parent_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('event.id'), nullable=True)
    children = db.relationship('Event', backref=db.backref('parent', lazy='noload', remote_side=[id]), lazy='noload')

class Node(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    events = db.relationship('Event', backref=db.backref('node', lazy='noload'), lazy='noload')
```

An event can have many child events and every event is associated with a single node.

I am able join the nodes and child events onto the parent events, which is straightforward. However I need the children events to also have their respective node joined. Is there a way to achieve this using the sqlalchemy orm?

This is my current query that doesn't join the nodes onto the children events:

```
event_alias = aliased(Event)
query = Event.query.outerjoin(Event.node) \
        .options(contains_eager(Event.node)) \
        .outerjoin(Event.children.of_type(event_alias)) \
        .options(contains_eager(Event.children.of_type(event_alias)))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution

```
event_alias = aliased(Event) 
node_alias = aliased(Node) 
query = Event.query.outerjoin(Event.node) \
    .options(contains_eager(Event.node)) \
    .outerjoin(Event.children.of_type(event_alias)) \
    .options(contains_eager(Event.children.of_type(event_alias))) \
    .outerjoin(event_alias.node.of_type(node_alias)) \
    .options(contains_eager(Event.children.of_type(event_alias), event_alias.node.of_type(node_alias)))
```